# Datatables Responsive extension in a Form not working

Tags: forms, datatables

I have a Datatable using the Responsive extension. It is working perfectly on my site OUTSIDE of the form.

Once I put it INSIDE the form, it no longer responds with the child rows.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to do with the way I was calling the 2 scripts and initializing.

Problem solved!